# How to determine if a function exists in a script that is BEING included

Tags: php, php-8

I have a script that I am auto_prepending using php.ini's auto_prepend_file setting

Within that script I would like to check to see if a function is defined in the called script. For instance

auto_prepend_script.php

```
<?php
if (function_exists('testFunction') {
    echo testFunction();
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}
?>
```

main_script.php

```
<?php
if (function_exists('testFunction') {
    echo testFunction();
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}

function testFunction() {
    echo "I EXIST!";
}
?>
```

If I call the script like `php main_script.php` :

I get the output:

```
FALSE
I EXIST!
```

Is there anyway, to get the output to be:

```
I EXIST!
I EXIST!
```

Comment: Since it's being prepended, the main script hasn't been included yet, so the function isn't loaded yet. And you can't really inspect a file before it is being included. So… not… really… possible…

Comment: In `auto_prepend_script.php` you *might* be able to examine `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` to determine which file was requested, and thus is *about* to be included (in this case `main_script.php`), read the contents of that file, call `ob_start()`, call `eval()` on the contents of the file, call `ob_end_clean()`, and then check if `function_exists(...)`. But even if this works, it's an epic kludge, and highly discouraged.

Comment: Note that even if you could check that the function was about to exist, you wouldn't be able to call it, because it doesn't exist yet - it would be like saying "I can see you're pregnant, can I shake your baby's hand". I suspect there's an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/237313) here - if you describe the problem you're actually trying to solve, there may be a solution, but this approach is a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

@deceze is right, you can't check if a function is existed before it's loaded. However, you can write the code to check for function existance after it's loaded in your preprended file with the help of `register_shutdown_function`

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    if (function_exists('testFunction')) {
        echo testFunction(), " later";
    } else {
        echo "FALSE";
    }
});
```

The output will be something like

```
I EXIST!
I EXIST! later
```